# Renaming Files in Finder using Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos

When renaming files in Finder I end the renaming with "Enter" which irritatingly opens the file. Websearch tells me that the "Enter"-key should start (and end) renaming while Cmd+O opens a file.

How do I restore that behaviour or by which keycommand has it been replaced? Did I change this myself (inadvertently, like, a while ago), or has Apple changed it??

EDIT:
After getting the answer that this behaviour has NOT changed, I looked into what could have changed it again and found that I activated this behaviour in **Karabiner-Elements**. Probably should have tried to get used to the system before customising it.

Comment: what OSX is it ? it does not do that on High Sierra.

Comment: this behaviour I have since High Sierra, but it stays this way on Mojave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that I activated this behaviour in Karabiner-Elements myself.